# Javascript Parasitic Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm struggling with Javascript **classical Inheritance** [<sup>1</sup>](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html). While, in the end **Douglas Crockford**, rejects its first attemps to support classical model in Javascript, I find it interesting to understand:

> I have been writing JavaScript for 8 years now, and I have never once found need to use an uber function. The super idea is fairly important in the classical pattern, but it appears to be unnecessary in the prototypal and functional patterns. I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake.

However, there is something not really clear for what concerns **Parasitic Inheritance**:

```
function ZParenizor2(value) {
   var that = new Parenizor(value);
   that.toString = function () {
      if (this.getValue()) {
         return this.uber('toString');
      }
      return "-0-"
   };
   return that;
 }
```

ZParenizor, as far I've understood is defined in terms of Parenizor. But Parenizor is the base class and it inherits from nobody. So `this.uber` function will not be defined and in fact I've an error when I call the `toString` method of a new ZParenizor2 object.

Am I correct, or I'm ignoring something?

**UPDATE**
I was right. This method only works when you create ZParenizor with 0 as parameter, since it does not need to call the `uber` method (as you can see form the method imeplementation).

When you try it with a different parameter, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'uber'
```

Comment: All objects inherit at least from `Object.prototype`...

Comment: Well, what does the error say?

Comment: Yes. The error was not due to what I thinked, but a typo. However I've not thinked about the fact that all objects inherit from Functions which are objects. Thanks!

Comment: All objects inherit from `Object.prototype` because `Object.prototype` is the end of **all** prototype chains. Functions additionally inherit from `Function.prototype`, but non-function objects don't inherit from that one.

Comment: So, one thing i want to know. Parenizor is a Function obect? I would answer yes, since its constructor is a function, and so is prototype... right?

Comment: But the instances of constructor functions (the objects returned by `new X()` **do not** inherit from the constructor functions directly. The fact that constructor functions inherit from `Function.prototype` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @SimeVidas `(Object.create(null)).toString() === TypeError` Objects don't need to have a prototype. However not having one is silly.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I've update the post. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Oh God, I'm so happy someone noticed this weirdness too. I thought I was having a stroke! There's also a `swiss()` method, which is also not defined.

All of these methods are defined later, in the 'Sugar' part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify Parenizor's prototype to have a uber function and it will work with any other value.

Comment: You're right. But the fact that author decided to give a uber function only to those inheriting objects, make me think.

Comment: Yes in that context it seems completely useless, however that would only depend on what use is given to the 'inheriting' object